# Modifying complex JSON Data in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a complex JSON in a column in a table.

The JSON has `sections` array. Each `sections` my or may not have `subSections` array. And each element of `subSections` may or may not have `attachments` array.

`attachments` array finally have just comma separated strings.

```
"attachments": [
            "Something",
            "Mango",
            "Banana",
            "Fruit"
            ]
```

I want to write a sql query which empties all `attachments` in JSON column for all rows in a table.

For above example, after running the query, the JSON should be:

```
"attachments": []
```

I can do the following to update:

```
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(MY_JSON_COL, '$.sections[0].subSections[0].attachments', JSON_QUERY('[]')) as result from MY_TABLE
```

However, this would just result in modifying `attachments` of first `subSection` in first `section`.

How do I write a generic query to empty all `attachments` in all `sections` and all `subSections` ?

Is it possible to empty all `attachments` of all `subSections` of all `sections` ?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: ...is there a reason you can't normalize your database so you're not storing JSON in a table?

Comment: SQL Server has nothing in the way of languages like XPath or XQuery but for JSON, so this sort of exercise is painful, basically requiring you to explode the data to the desired level using `OPENJSON`, modifying it in the query as necessary and then reassembling it again with `FOR JSON`.

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)